# Aurelia Layout View Binding Scope

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am trying to use a layout view. The module I am using the layout view is called dashboard. I have this fragment in my layout view:

```
<div class="manage-btn" click.delegate="manageClick()">MANAGE ACCOUNT</div>
```

this is my dashboard.html:

```
<template>     

  <router-view layout-view="src/layouts/dash-layout.html"></router-view>

</template>
```

then in my dashboard.js I have the function:

```
manageClick() {

    if (this.profileDropClass === '') {
        this.profileDropClass = 'show';
    }
    else {
        this.profileDropClass = '';
    }

}// manageClick()
```

I keep getting an error that says the manageClick() is not a function. I have functionality that I want to reside within the layout view, is this not possible? If I have to repeat this functionality, what good is the layout view?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to define the layout-viewmodel and or model. Take a look at the following blog post for more details https://www.google.at/amp/s/charlespockert.wordpress.com/2016/07/05/using-the-layouts-feature-in-aurelia/amp/